# Error deserializing JSON containing value in format "0.0n"

Tags: json, .net, deserialization, system.text.json

Working on a project using .NET 7.0 and System.Text.Json to deserialize JSON to basic POCO classes and running into the following error:

```
The JSON value could not be converted to Models.ESPN.Clock. Path: $.status.clock | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 6823.
```

Below is the JSON related to the error:

```
{
   "status":{
      "clock":{
         "value":"0.0n",
         "type":"Big Number"
      },
      "displayClock":"0:00",
      "period":4
   }
}
```

And the related POCO classes:

```
public class Status
{
    public Clock clock { get; set; }
    public string displayClock { get; set; }
    public double period { get; set; }
}

public class Clock
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

*Note: JSON and classes are snippets from larger data set. Minimized to data set related to error.*

From debugging the JSON deserialization seems to be throwing exemption trying to map the JSON $.status.clock.value of "0.0n". I have tried setting the type as string, int, and BigInteger and all results in same error.

How do I handle a JSON value of "0.0n" in my class?

Dot Net Fiddle reproducible code:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/7q5xtq

Comment: I have just created a new .NET 7 console app, pasted the above code into it, removed the `status` element from the JSON, called `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Status>` on it, and it deserialises just fine. Voting to close question as not reproducible.

Comment: @IanKemp Here is a reproduceable example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7q5xtq

Comment: That actual JSON from https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/college-football/teams/2305 makes it quite obvious what the problem is. The JSON document, **which is different to what you posted in the question**, has `"clock": 0.0` which you are trying to deserialise into the `Clock` class with two separate fields - this very obviously will not work. If you change your `Status` class to have `public double clock { get; set; }` then deserialisation works fine.

Comment: If you really want/need your `Clock` class that is basically converting the value to a string and splitting on the `.` then you need to write a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to).

Comment: @IanKemp You are right! I was viewing the JSON in a browser plug-in (https://webextension.org/listing/json-beautifier.html) which was not parsing the JSON correctly [https://ibb.co/JnVnyfM]. Viewing the raw JSON it is obvious https://ibb.co/j8Z9xV3. Leason learned to avoid plug-ins and just view the raw JSON response. Sorry to bother with this and thanks for your feedback.

Comment: EDIT: Screenshot of browser plug-in which was not parsing the JSON response correctly and causing issue:  https://ibb.co/JnVnyfM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit @IanKemp for pointing me in the right direction. Turned out a browser plug-in was not parsing the JSON response correctly in which I was creating my POCO classes. Lesson learned to not use browser plug-ins! See post comments for more details.